# Spring Boot H2 Version Warning

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I'm using spring boot with H2 database. On the previous version of H2 (h2-1.3.173), the TO_CHAR function was not supported. To resolve this problem, I updated my H2 version to (h2-1.4.182), which now works.

However, when I ran my spring-boot application I got this error message "Connection is broken: "unexpected status 16843008", which I looked around and the root cause is due to different h2 jdbc versions.

I checked my spring-boot reference and it used (h2-1.3.176). So, I tried to updated the pom.xml of spring-boot. But there is a warning "Overriding managed version 1.3.176 for h2". Did clean install and it worked.

However, I am a bit worried about this warning, any spring-boot experts can confirm it is not causing any hidden problem?

Comment: I suggest to append ";mv_store=false" to the database URL if you use version 1.4.x, because the new storage (MVStore) in version 1.4 is still beta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring Boot 1.1.x should work fine with H2 1.4.x. Also, you may be interested to know that the recently released 1.2.0 of Spring Boot uses H2 1.4.x by default.

As you've seen, the warning is coming from Maven. Assuming you're using `spring-boot-starter-parent` as your pom's parent, you've inherited dependency management for `com.h2database:h2`. If you want to continue to use Spring Boot 1.1.x but without the warning from Maven, you can do so by overriding the `h2.version` property in your pom:

```
<properties>
    <h2.version>1.4.182</h2.version>
</properties>
```

And then declaring the dependency without a version:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thanks @Andy, I upgraded to Spring boot 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

That warning is harmless. It's not directly from maven but its m2e issued warning which can be suppressed by adding a comment in pom.xml ***just after version tag*** like below([source](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=346725)):

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.200</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$--> 
        <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```